# Did Krishna ever prayed to another God like Brahma or Shiva?

Tags: bhagavata-purana

It is known that Ram prayed to Shiva and Goddess Durga to conquer Ravana.

My question is : did Krishna also ever prayed to another God like Brahma or Shiva?

Comment: Krishna most probably prayed to Rudra.

Comment: @iammilind source?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(Krishna%27s_son)#Birth

Comment: Possible duplicate(s) of [Where is it mentioned that Krishna and Rama Worshipped Shiva Lingam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9986/3500) and [Why Nãrãyana (Vishnu) had to pray Rudra (Shiva) to obtain supreme powers? (excerpt from Mahãbhãrata)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7376/3500)

Comment: But why did he pray to another demi-god when he himself has said that those who pray to demi-gods pray in the wrong way?

Comment: See here:http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_074.html and here http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07077.htm and here. http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a014.htm

Comment: Lord Shiva is not a demigod,Making Lord Shiva demigod is a concept Of iskcon,no scripture mentiones Lord Shiva being a  demigod,Boht Gods(Vishnu and Shiva) are supreme and we should treat them equal

Comment: @DheerajVerma Lord Shiva is not demi God. Some Vaishnava Philosophies consider Shiva as Demi God, not all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Krishna praised Shiva for getting son, mentioned in [Devi Bhagvatam, 4.25](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk04ch25.htm):

> 28-29. On seeing Rukminî’s many sons, Pradyûmna and others, all qualified with diverse qualifications, His wife Jâmbavatî prayed to S’rî Krisna with humility, so that she may have also many beautiful sons. For her sake, Krisna firmly resolved to practise tapasyâ and went to the place where the great devotee of S’iva, Upamanyu, was staying.
>
> 30. Hari desiring to have sons engaged Upamanyu as His spiritual guide and obtained from him the Mantram called Pâs’upata Mantra and became a Dundee (holder of a staff) and shaved His head.
>
> 31-32. In the first month He subsisted on fruits only and meditated on S’iva and repeated silently the S’iva mantra. Thus He practised very severe austerities. In the second month He subsisted on water only and stood on only one leg. In the third month he lived on air only and stood on the end of His great toe.
>
> 33-36. Thus time passed away. In the sixth month the God Rudra, holding Moon on His forehead, was pleased with His asceticism and devotion and appeared before Him on that spot. The God Mahâ Deva came on a bull; He was attended by Brahmâ  and Visnu, Indra and the other Devas, Yakshas and Gandarbhas and addressed thus :-- “O high minded Krisna of Yadu’s descent; I am pleased with Your severe asceticism; now ask Your desired boon; I will grant it just now. I fulfil all the desires of all my devotees;
>
> 37-38. Vyâsa said :-- The son of Devakî was very glad to see the God S’amkara and fell prostrate at His feet. Then that eternal supreme God of the Devas began to recite hymns in praise of Him in a tone as deep as the rumbling of a cloud.
>
> 39. Krisna said :-- O Deva of the Devas! O Lord of the world! You alone destroy the misfortunes and sorrows of all the beings. O Destroyer of Asuras! You are the Cause and Creator of this universe. I salute Thee.