# When did Sri Krishna worship Goddess Durga?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, durga, chandipath

In the Argalastotra of Sri Srri Chandi (which is a part of the Markandeya Purana) we get:

> कृष्णेन संस्तुते देवि शश्वद्भक्त्या सदाम्विके
>
> Meaning : O Goddess! Lord Krishna worshipped you regularly with extreme devotion.

The rishi of this mantra is Vishnu Himself.

My question is: Is there any reference in our holy scriptures of Lord Krishna or Vishnu regularly worshipping the Mother Goddess?

Comment: Related or Possibly Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21472/did-krishna-ever-prayed-to-another-god-like-brahma-or-shiva

Comment: Not a duplicate @SwiftPushkar. That only deals with worship of Shiva by Krishna. This is different and asking about Durga and a specific verse.

Comment: I was taught that Krishn meditated on Shakti in several different forms, and also he meditated on Manasa Devi.