# What is relationship between Krishna and Shiva so they worship each other?

Tags: shiva, krishna, worship

How Krishna and Shiva are related to each other so they worship each other?

Are they same?

Comment: In the Scriptures most of the times they are one and the same. In the sectarian philosophy, not so much.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-n%c3%a3r%c3%a3yana-vishnu-had-to-pray-rudra-shiva-to-obtain-supreme-powers-excer  **&**  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/why-doesnt-shiva-worship-anybody-where-as-vishnu-worships-him-in-all-his-incarn